# In 'You've got me there!', what does 'there' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, word-meaning

> ‘What’s the capital of Bulgaria?’
> ‘You’ve got me there!’

In 'You've got me there!', what does 'there' mean?

[Dictionary you've got me there](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/you%27ve+got+me+there)

1. That is a question or problem to which I do not know the answer or solution.
   A: "The plan sounds good, but what do we do if the boss comes back early?" B: "Hmm, you got me there. Run, I guess."
   A: "What's the circumference of the earth, Dad?" B: "You've got me there, I have no idea!"
2. You have pointed something out that I am unable to explain, refute, or deny.
   A: "Yes, but isn't it true that you accepted campaign donations from several corporations that are lobbying against this proposal?" B: "Well, you got me there."
   A: "Don't you think this approach would be a much better use of our resources?" B: "Hmm, you've got me there. That does make more sense."
   See also: there
   you've got me there
3. I do not know.
   A: "How do we open this panel?" B: "You've got me there. We'll have to consult the manual."
4. You have proven me wrong on this one point.
   A: "But didn't you just say there were no exceptions?" B: "Well, you've got me there. It does seem like there are some rare cases where the rule doesn't apply."

Comment: See my comment on your other question.

Comment: *You've got me **there*** = *You've got me **with that***, where ***there*** and ***that*** are "adverbial" references to whatever point / question was just raised by the addressee. It could just as well be some other adverbial qualifier such as ***here, now, with this, at last,...*** - some of which may carry slight nuances of different emphasis, but basically they all refer to the *immediate / nearby / recent* context.

Comment: It's a pat phrase. What exactly are you looking for in an answer? Do you know what "there" means? Do you know what "You've got me" means?

Comment: "You've got me." means "You've caught me. or You made me embarrased." and "there" means "a place where somebody is pointing or the direction somebody is pointing for"

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think you are very specialized in explaining very well things that askers don't know and thus want to hear through questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fairly standard expression (I suppose that it could be considered an idiom), but the meaning of "there" is quite ordinary. From [Merriam-Webster's definitions](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/there), I think that #4 works best:

> 4: in that matter, respect, or relation
> // *there* is where I disagree with you

Comment: Your answer is short, simple but crystal-clear.